# File not downloading from GridView on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, response.transmitfile

I have a `GridView` named **gvEmplAttachments** that has 3 columns:

- id
- FileName
- FilePath

Each row has a `LinkButton` that will allows the user to download the file, that button is coded as such:

```
<asp:LinkButton  id="lbViewFile" runat="server" CommandName="ViewFile" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' >View</asp:LinkButton>
```

The GridView is set with the following:

```
OnRowCommand ="gvEmplAttachments_OpenAttachment_RowCommand"
```

So that it will execute the function in the CodeBehind

---

In my CodeBehind I have this function:

```
protected void gvEmplAttachments_OpenAttachment_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ViewFile")
    {
        //Get rowindex
        int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //Get the Row
        GridViewRow gvr = gvUaSettings.Rows[rowindex];
        //Get the Needed Values
        Label lblPath = gvr.FindControl("lblFilePath") as Label;
        Label lblName = gvr.FindControl("lblFileName") as Label;
        //String The values
        string fileName = lblName.Text;
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(lblPath.Text);
        //Should Download the file
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
        response.TransmitFile(filePath);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
}
```

But the problem is when I click the button I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

My question is, what am I missing that would be causing the null value. 
Because the Grid is displaying the correct FileName and FilePath.

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned your **Gridview ID** is `gvEmplAttachments`, but the code you written to grab the row of Gridview which trigger **OnCommand** event is having different gridview ID `GridViewRow gvr = gvUaSettings.Rows[rowindex];` is this correct or code misplace? May it didn't get the proper Gridview Row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Rojalin Sahoo good catch! that corrected the issue. - if you submit this as an answer I will mark it for you.

Comment: @Tommy,Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned your Gridview ID is **gvEmplAttachments**, but the code you written to grab the row of Gridview which trigger OnCommand event is having different Gridview ID 
`GridViewRow gvr = gvUaSettings.Rows[rowindex];`.

You can try for the following Code to fetch the row triggering command event:

`GridViewRow gvr = gvEmplAttachments.Rows[rowindex];`